Unable to display picture from firebase database, I'm able to store data in database, they are stored in form:com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw@7726d68
The getdownloadurl method is deprecated , I'm able to store data in database, they are stored in form:com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw@7726d68 ,Unable to display picture from firebase database,  I am not able to understand how to redo my code, Here's my code -

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.util.HashMap;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText UserName, FullName, CountryName;
    private Button SaveInformationbutton;
    private CircleImageView ProfileImage;

    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;

    private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;

    String currentUserID;

    final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);

        UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");


        UserName = findViewById(R.id.setup_username);
        FullName = findViewById(R.id.setup_full_name);
        CountryName = findViewById(R.id.setup_country_name);

        SaveInformationbutton = findViewById(R.id.setup_information_button);

        ProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.setup_profile_image);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        SaveInformationbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SaveAccountSetupInformation();


            }
        });

        ProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,Gallery_Pick);




            }
        });

        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists())
                {
                    if(snapshot.hasChild("profileimage"))
                    {
                        String image = snapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();

                                   

Picasso.with(SetupActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(ProfileImage);


                        Glide.with(SetupActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(ProfileImage);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"Please select profile image first.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }




                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });











    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
        {
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setAspectRatio(1,1).start(this);




        }

        if(requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {

                loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are updating your profile image....");
                loadingBar.show();
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();


                StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                    {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image stored successfully to Firebase storage...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                        {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                                            {
                                                Intent selfIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(selfIntent);

                                                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image stored to Firebase Database Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error Occured: Image could not be cropped.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }


        }

    }

    private void SaveAccountSetupInformation() {

        String username = UserName.getText().toString();
        String fullname = FullName.getText().toString();
        String country =  CountryName.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please write your Username",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)) {

            Toast.makeText(this,"Please write your Full name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(country)) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please write your Country name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else {

            loadingBar.setTitle("Saving Information");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are creating your Account....");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
            userMap.put("username",username);
            userMap.put("fullname",fullname);
            userMap.put("country", country);
            userMap.put("status", "Hey there! I am using Firechat social network, developed by Anand Puranik");
            userMap.put("gender", "none");
            userMap.put("dob", "none");
            userMap.put("relationshipstatus", "none");

            UsersRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"your Account is created Successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                    else {
                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"Error Occured" + message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });

        }


    }















Here's my xml code -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_register"
    tools:context=".SetupActivity">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/setup_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/setup_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/setup_profile_image"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputs"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="14dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/setup_full_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/setup_username"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputs"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="14dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/setup_country_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/setup_full_name"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputs"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/country"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="Country"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_information_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/setup_country_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="Save"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>






























Here's my MainActivity.java code -

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private RecyclerView postList;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private CircleImageView NavProfileImage;

    private TextView NavProfileUserName;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;

    String currentUserID;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);

        NavProfileImage = navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_image);

        NavProfileUserName = navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_full_name);


        UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if(snapshot.exists())
                {
                    if(snapshot.hasChild("fullname"))
                    {
                        String fullname = snapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                        NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
                    }
                    if(snapshot.hasChild("profileimage"))
                    {
                        String image = snapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();


                        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);

                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Profile name do not exist.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }





                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });






        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                UserMenuSelector(menuItem);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null)
        {
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
        else {
            CheckUserExistence();
        }
    }

    private void CheckUserExistence() {

        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if(!snapshot.hasChild(current_user_id))
                {
                    SendUserToSetupActivity();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }

    private void SendUserToSetupActivity() {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SetupActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();

    }

    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {

        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void UserMenuSelector(MenuItem menuItem) {

        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_friends) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Friend List", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_find_friends) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Find Friends", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_messages) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Messages", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Logout) {

            mAuth.signOut();
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
    }
}








Here are my gradle dependencies - 

<

dependencies {


implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.activity
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.firebase.auth
    implementation libs.design
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core


    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'

}








>









































































getDownloadUrl returns a Task.  You can't just call toString on it to get a useful URL - you have to use the results of the task to find the URL.

Can you elaborate a little more with code changes in my code.

There is a code sample in the duplicate that I marked here, and also in the documentation.
